# Creating javascript list from python list using jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I am trying to create a javascript list from a python list using jinja2. My current implementation is this:

```
var go_words = [{{"\"" + user.names | join('\",\"') + "\""}}]
```

which yields:

```
var go_words = [&#39;Name 1&#39;, ...]
```

For some reason the `"` character is not being interpreted correctly and thus my script is failing. Is there anyway to fix this? Note that my code for this javascript is in an html `<script>` tag which is included from another html template.

Even an inline list in the jinja brackets yields and incorrect list

```
var go_words = {{["test", "test1", "test2"]}}


var go_words = [&#39;test&#39;, &#39;test1&#39;, &#39;test2&#39;]
```

Comment: I don't have it right in front of me, but doesn't `{{user.names}}` do what you need?

Comment: @MarkMeyer it does remove the complexity I had for the join code above but it still formats the `"` incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `safe` filter to prevent Jinja from escaping templated values. For example:

```
var goWords = {{ user.names|safe }};
```